# Is it possible for an application to uninstall itself after a period of time?

Tags: android

I am planning to give my app to a client as a trial, and I wish for it to be automatically uninstalled after some time. My app does not need an internet connection. Can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

First of all, uninstall app automatically is not good way. Try to disable all features.

Generally, you need the following algorithm:

1) On starting your app (for example in first activity) get SharedPreferences (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and check key with date of first start (for example "firstStartDate"). Also, reads key "lastStartDate".

2) If key "firstStartDate" doesn't exist - it's first start of your app, get current date and write it as value of both keys, than continue normal work of app.

3) If key "firstStartDate" exists - get current date and check that your trial is not expired (claculate days count between first start and current date). Also, check that current date is more or equal date in "lastStartDate" (protection from date changing on device). If current date is less than "lastStartDate" - it's date hack and user moved time. In this case you can finish trial (see point 5).

4) If trial is not expired - OK, continue normal work and write current date into "lastStartDate".

5) If expired - show to user dialog (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) about expired trial with parameter cancellable=false and close activity on clicking dialog button.

I think this will much better than just uninstall application.

Comment: Hi Dimmerg,Thank you for reply.but in that case when user change his device date he can use my app for long time I am not going to validate these things.How can I validate these things.

Comment: I mean that your package can't uninstall itself and write you how to better implement your trial functionality.

Comment: Thank you Dimmerg.I will disabled the feature.Thank you..>!

Comment: Hi Dimmerg, I will follow u'r first comment but when user changes his device date frequently then my app trial period never over.In that case how we can proceed.Sory for my poor english.

Comment: Updated my post according your problem.

Comment: If you find a answer helpful and that solves your question, accept the answer.